# ArcMap: Joining Tables for the Labeling Manager

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have two tables I would like to join, in an mdb, and have the label manager display columns from the joined table. I am able to do this through the ArcMap Gui (right clicking a layer and making a join through "Joins and Relates"), but I would like to do this programmatically. Is this possible?

I joined the two tables by following this example: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002zw000000 but the label manager does not seem to recognize this join and as a result I am missing columns.

Thanks

Edit: I am working in C#.

Comment: Are you saying you want to do it in Python? if so http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Add_Join/001700000064000000/ please provide more information on the language you want to use.

Comment: I am working in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have it... the example you are using creates the join for program internal processes and does not add it to the layer. Here is one that I've done previously (it's in VB but C# is very similar)

```
If fJoin.Checked Then
  Dim pMemRelClassFact As IMemoryRelationshipClassFactory = New MemoryRelationshipClassFactory
  Dim pRelClass As IRelationshipClass2 = pMemRelClassFact.Open("Mem", pFLayer.FeatureClass, "OBJECTID", pTable, "LinkID", "For", "Bk", esriRelCardinality.esriRelCardinalityOneToOne)
  'Dim pRqtFact As IRelQueryTableFactory = New RelQueryTableFactoryClass
  Dim pDisplayRel As IDisplayRelationshipClass = pFLayer
  pDisplayRel.DisplayRelationshipClass(pRelClass, esriJoinType.esriLeftInnerJoin)
```

The key here is the `IDisplayRelationshipClass` which associates the join with the feature layer.

so in C# you need to add this to the end of the sample for joining:

```
IDisplayRelationshipClass DispRelClass = (IDisplayRelationshipClass)YourLayer;
DispRelClass.DisplayRelationshipClass(relationshipClass,esriJoinType.esriLeftInnerJoin);
```

I hope this helps, or at least makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work for me. For IMemoryRelationshipClassFactory.Open I am not sure what to put for ForwardPathLabel and BackwardPathLabel or even Name. I just put them as dummy strings. Regardless the join works.